# Case sensitive IN clause

Tags: vertica

I need to check for the existence of e-mails from a Google Form within my Vertica Database.

If they exist, they will show me the ID associated with it.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE email IN ('email1','email2'...)
```

It is not showing e-mails where people mistakenly used upper case letters. It's a LONG list of responses from my Google Form, how can I do the IN clause case insensitive?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LOWER`.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE LOWER(email) IN (LOWER('email1'),LOWER('email2')...)
```

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/LOWER.htm